# bootstrap breakpoints... need some clarification ' xs sm md lg'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So.. looking online, I see some recent articles stating that the xs breakpoint is 480px and below.. others.. state 767 and below..

I had the understanding (probably not correct) that xs was for phones (480px and below), .col-sm is for tablets (480 px to 767px) etc..

However, when I apply .hidden-xs -- it seems to hide where I would expect my tablet view... in the 480px to 767 range...

What am I doing wrong here?

The columns snap to stacking at 480px, but the .hidden features and .col-xs do not seem to change at that screen width.

I'm working with some crazy legacy code, but i'm fairly certain I've upgraded to the latest version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The xs breakpoint actually handles screens from 767 pixels and below. The breakpoint widths are as follows:

- **xs**= 0-767 pixels
- **sm** = 768-991 pixels
- **md** = 992-1199 pixels
- **lg** = 1200 pixels and up

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

PLEASE NOTE THIS ANSWER IS FOR VERSION 3.0

Comment: Note this is fixed in Bootstrap v4: xs is now at 480px. They also added more descriptive responsive classes e.g. `hidden-md-up`. See migration doc: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: @kitsu.eb Related to the [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) it is 544px, not 480px.

Comment: Note that in Bootstrap v4, instead of `col-xs-*` you should use `col-*`

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this while trying to gain clarity on the same topic, albeit **for Bootstrap 4.**

- **xs**= 0 - 575.98 pixels (**max-width 575.98**) Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
- **sm** = 575.99 - 767.98 pixels (**max-width 767.98**) Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
- **md** = 767.99 - 991.98 pixels (**max-width 991.98**) Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
- **lg** = 991.99 - 1199.98 pixels (**max-width 1199.98**)  Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
- **xl** = 1199.99 pixels and up (**min-width 1199.99**) Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for Bootstrap v5.0**

Here's a list of updated grid sizes for Bootstrap5

- **xs** < *576px*
- **sm** ≥ *576px*
- **md** ≥ *768px*
- **lg** ≥ *992px*
- **xl** ≥ *1200px*
- **xxl** ≥ *1400px*

See [Bootstrap5 grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)