# What is happening to my grid system? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why are my pictures lining up strangely at col-sm-6? I understand that at that point each row should two pictures in a row. However, they are stacking strangely and I am left with two pictures in one row and a row of one picture below that. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

[image]

I need every row to have two pictures on at col-sm-6

Comment: Because `col-sm-6` calculate 50% width & `col-sm-4` calculate 33.33% width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `row` class starts a new row block where columns are laid out one after another. In order to display grid view you should place all items in a single row.

In your broken case each row contains up to 3 columns - that is why the third item has no sibling as the next row is rendered underneath.

Please see following snippet (expand it to see media queries in action):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example using `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2` [Bootrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/640/450" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-xss-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img src="img/decking.jpg">
    </div>

Comment: at extra extra small I am trying to make the pictures go full width but it still isn't working

Comment: they are staying as two in a row

Comment: There are no col-xss-{number} in Bootstrap by default. Please use xs breakpoint or [redefine Bootsrap's grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066059/bootstrap-3-adding-a-new-set-of-columns).

Comment: So if I wanted all the pictures to be 100% width at 500px I have to create my own breakpoint?

Comment: That is why I thought col-xs-12 would work but it doesn't.

Comment: col-xs-12 should do the job as it is defined as `width: 100%` and should span whole row unitil hitting [`sm` breakpoint at 768px](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29837346/1384679). Maybe you are overriding it somewhere. Please post your test case. However, if you want to break at 500px exactly then use raw media queries.

Answer (score 1):

No need to repeat `row` class

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="img/moss.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap `col-sm-6` has 50% width & `col-sm-4` has 33.33% width so that you need to used `col-sm-4` if you want three image per row.

```css
.img-responsive {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" >
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.phoronix.com/assets/categories/linuxgaming.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```